# Python requests works on PowerShell but it doesn't on WSL

Tags: python, python-requests, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to execute :

```
r = requests.post( url, headers=headers, data = payload, cert=(ca_cert,ca_key))
```

in PowerShell it works but when I try on WSL I get:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe26fb668d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cm-squiceno-nsw-invote-dev.iaas.scytlprojects.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /credential-manager-webapp/services/iVoteCreateVBP (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe26fb668d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./one_credential.py", line 48, in <module>
    r = requests.post( url, headers=headers, data = payload, cert=(ca_cert,ca_key))
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/steven/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cm-squiceno-nsw-invote-dev.iaas.scytlprojects.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /credential-manager-webapp/services/iVoteCreateVBP (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe26fb668d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Answer (score -1):

It was a problem with the DNS.
I fix it running this function on WSL:

```
vpn() {
[ -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf -a -L /etc/resolv.conf ] && sudo cp --remove-destination /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
local sudo="sudo"
if [ -w /etc/resolv.conf ]; then sudo=""; fi
$sudo ed -s /etc/resolv.conf <<'EOF'
H
a
#EOF
.
kx
g/^nameserver /d
.-1r !/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command '$x = Get-NetAdapter | Group-Object -AsHashtable -Property ifIndex; Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily ipv4 | where {$x[$_.InterfaceIndex].Status -eq "Up"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses | foreach {"nameserver " + $_}' | sed 's/\r//g'
'xd
wq
EOF
}
```

found here: https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-fails-to-use-dns-from-a-vpn-tunnel/190912103759019/